# Fourier Series Coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I'm working on the following problem for my PDE's class as study for a test.

> Sketch the Fourier series of 
>   $$ f(x) = 2x^2$$ 
>   On the interval of $[-1,1]$.

My professors answer key states that the Fourier series for this function is $2x^2$ repeated over the interval $[-1,1]$ (I'd post the graph, but I'm not sure how.)

My understanding of the Fourier series is that for any function $f(x)$ is given by

$$ A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos\bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \bigg ) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \sin\bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \bigg ) \tag{1}\label{1} $$

Where 
 $$ A_0  = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) dx$$
 $$ A_n =  \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) \cos\bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \bigg )dx$$
 $$ B_n =  \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin\bigg(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \bigg )dx$$

There are easier techniques to graphing the Fourier series of some function, but in attempting to solve this problem the hard way I find that

$$ A_0 = \frac{2}{3} $$
$$ A_n = \frac{8}{(n \pi)^2} (-1)^n $$
$$ B_n = 0 $$

When you plug these coefficients into $(\ref{1})$, you do not get $2x^2$ as my professor states.

I've worked this problem three times now and cannot seem to find my mistake. So my question, what are the correct coefficients for $f(x)$ along the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I think that your professor means that the *sum* of the fourier series is equal to the value of the function $f(x)=2x^2$ repeated over [-1,1] for every value of $x$. This because the series converges, and it's not interesting what its fourier coefficients look like. Remember, you should only sketch the graph here.

Comment: @Scounged, even then, $\frac{2}{3}$ + the sum for $A_n$ doesn't converge to $2x^2$.

Comment: Why not? ${}{}$

Comment: Don't understand what problem you have: the coefficients you found are correct, and inserted in the formula do approach $2*x^2$ !

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The sum of $A_n \cos(n \pi x)$  converges to 0. Since $B_n = 0 $, the Fourier series is 2/3. I know this is wrong, but I don't know why.

Comment: Why does $\sum A_n \cos (n \pi x)$ converge to $0$?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+goes+to+infinity+of+8%2F(n*pi)%5E2+cos(n*pi*x)

Comment: @Kosta For example, when $x=1$, then $\cos(n \pi x) = \cos(n \pi) = (-1)^n$.  So your sum becomes, at $x=1$, the value $\frac23 + \frac8{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}$, which is a sum of all positive terms...

Comment: In any case, Scounged is right, you do not need to compute the coefficients in order to know what the series converges to, since there is a theorem that tells us what it converges to, namely what your professor said:  the periodic extension of the original function.